# Terraform plan not recognizing argument in terraform cloud in certain environment

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to add the attribute "response_headers_policy" to the aws_cloudfront_distribution module. I have 3 environments: prod, stage, demo. Prod was the first created, followed by stage and demo a few months later. When adding that attribute to the staging and demo environments, there are no issues. However the plan fails with the following error when running for the prod environment:

```
Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on ../../modules/<module>/cloudfront.tf line 47, in resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "this":
│   47:     response_headers_policy_id = "67f7725c-6f97-4210-82d7-5512b31e9d03" // SecurityHeadersPolicy ID
│
│ An argument named "response_headers_policy_id" is not expected here.
```

My assumption is that the state file expects an older version of the module for the production environment, but I am unsure how to resolve that issue. Especially in terraform cloud.

Comment: I don't know terraform cloud, but with the cli you can do `terraform init -upgrade` as documented [here](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/init#upgrade) to get the latest versions that match your version strings.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is that there is a mismatch in what version of the AWS provider you're using for your different environments. That argument was only added to the AWS provider in [v3.64.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#3640-november-04-2021), in [#21620](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/21620).